# How to bring back Clipit's online Mode?

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

I'm not able to bring clipit back from offline mode to online

I can't find any proper documentation

Comment: open clipit configuration file in gedit and check if it contains the line `offline_mode=true` or not.
The clipit configuration file is located at `~/.config/clipit/clipitrc` .
If not just add it as last line `offline_mode=true` or if it is like `offline_mode=false` then change it to `offline_mode=true` .

Comment: thanks it was offline_mode=true but in this file i got shortcuts to get back to online mode  <Ctrl><Alt>O is the key

Comment: Good, So is it solved?

Comment: yes @Thor Odinson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clipit saves its configuration file at `~/.config/clipit/clipitrc`.

open clipit configuration file in gedit and check if it contains the line `offline_mode=true` or not. 
To open use

```
gedit ~/.config/clipit/clipitrc
```

If this line is not there, just add `offline_mode=true` as last line or if it is like `offline_mode=false` then change it to `offline_mode=true` .